# Sending emails via SMTP with postfix

Tags: postfix, smtp

I have a VPS in which I have installed and setup postfix as a send-only mail server.

This command here works perfectly fine to send mail
    echo "This email is a test" | mail -s "This is a test email" email@example.com

What I want to be able to do is send mail through it from a remote server using SMTP, however, it refuses the connection

Answer (score 0):

You likely need to bind postix to listen on interfaces other then local host. Modify /etc/postfix.conf

```
  inet_interfaces = YOUR.IP,127.0.0.1
```

or

```
  inet_interfaces = all
```

(You will also need to ensure your mynetworks line is correctly set so it knows what hosts can send through it)

And restart postfix.

Comment: The authorative source for basic configuration is http://www.postfix.org/BASIC_CONFIGURATION_README.html

Comment: it's very likely your VPS Provider has these ports blocked and a spam prevention technique

Comment: How do I create a login for the SMTP account?

Comment: https://wiki2.dovecot.org/HowTo/PostfixAndDovecotSASL